# Programming for Linux environment using visual studio and MONO

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-2013, mono

Before writing this I have gone through many articles, but dint find steps to follow. I found a plugin 'Monohelper'.
  Finally my requirement is to build an application using visual studio for linux environment which will be a console application, on which I will be using WebClient for connecting with internet . I am not familiar with linux environment. Can somebody share steps i need to follo to process ahead with visual studio and C# .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now much easier to get Mono and MonoDevelop installed on a typical Linux disto using Xamarin's feed,

http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin

And once that's done, you can easily follow steps such as

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/170/notes/CSharpHtml/lab-monodevelop.html

Forget about Visual Studio temporarily, as you won't get quite what you want at the beginner level without learning much of Linux and Mono. After playing Mono for a few weeks and noticing the differences, you can then see what Visual Studio can help.

Comment: thanks will try these steps , will get back if I find any issue.